# What was the ultimate resolution of "The President Is Missing"?

Tags: the-president-is-missing

*The President Is Missing* was a computer game back in the paleolithic era, roughly 1986, IIRC. It had a conspiracy theme, and was accompanied by a cassette tape of evidence. It was great fun, but I never unlocked any sort of definitive answer as to what the whole game was about.

Does anyone else here remember this game, and if so, do you have any thoughts on what was going on?

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_President_Is_Missing_(video_game)#Resolution), the game never actually ended. You are supposed to [write a report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_President_Is_Missing_(video_game)#Resolution) and send it to the game's creators.

So like a real government employee, you can write a report that can be ignored and buried. ;)

Comment: Yeah...I was kind of hoping that maybe someone had done that and written about it. Barring that, that somebody who had worked on the game knew.